# Figuring out the Most number of levels in a Binary tree.

Tags: trees

If we were given a specific number like 15, what approach can we use to determine the Maximum number of levels that can be present in a binary tree ?

Comment: Do you mean that if you are given a positive integer $n$, you want to know how to determine the largest positive integer exponent $\alpha$ such that $2^\alpha \leq n~$ ?

Comment: One good approach is to work out lots of examples. What are the trees with the most levels you can construct with $n$ nodes, for values of $n$ up to, say, 10?